# Export volume with Docker pull

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I am building two docker images on Gitlab CI/CD using a docker-compose, inside it I mount several volumes, their path is specified by a .env file.

The thing is, when I pull the image from the repo to a server I want to get my mounted volume back, so I wrote a script that create a .env file with a user input for specifying volume path, then I placed the .env file in a bind volume, so you can access it from the host and run the container with it

The script does great, but the file does not appears in the bind volume on the host, in fact none of my mount volumes appear.

I have tried nothing special yet, but I know that if I reuse a docker-compose or if I mount volume via docker run command it will work.
However, this is not optimal since I have many volume to mount and I cannot give an other docker-compose to the server.

I also know that it is possible to mount volume via gitlab-ci.yml but I saw some several advice against it.

Comment: You can only push and pull images, which in turn only contain the application code.  You can't push or pull volumes, and you need to move the data separately.  (You're highly likely to want to update the application itself but leave its data intact.)

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, so if I want my volume to be mount I can only do it with docker run and arguments or with a new docker-compose file ?